# Media Queries not working even though i have head tag

Tags: media-queries

My media tags dont seem 2 work even thought i have the viewport tag in my head. I am trying to change the font size when lowering the resolution. I am not sure what i am doing wrong but would love some help.

```
<? ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa One' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #bdc3c7">
    <div class="navBar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="pLbl" style="font-family: 'Changa One';">
        Enter Password to enter:
      </div>
      <div>
      <input class="pInput" id="pInp" type="password"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <button class="pBtn" onclick="pLogin()"></button>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Submit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


<style>
    .pLbl {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
  .pLbl {
  font-size 12px;
  }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you forgot the colon after font size on media query :)

**PS:** While modern browsers have a code correction for invalid HTML, I suggest you put style tag in your head, declare the doctype and write your inputs with self-close tag.